# Dispalying Column value depend on the particular condition otherwise displaying emply column value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following table

```
Id  col1 status Action

1    c    R     close

2    c    S     close

3    e    R     close

4    1    N     close

5    2    N    close

6    4    N     close
```

I want to display all the record with the following condition

1) Action column value will only when the status is N. Otherwise it will be empty

Required output

```
Id  col1 status Action

1    c    R   

2    c    S     

3    e    R     

4    1    N     close

5    2    N     close

6    4    N     close
```

I am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Any reply will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Id
    ,col1
    ,STATUS
    ,Action = CASE 
        WHEN [STATUS] = 'N'
            THEN [Action]
        ELSE ''
        END
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a query using [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

E.g.

```
SELECT Id, col1, status, CASE WHEN status = 'N' THEN Action ELSE '' END AS Action
FROM table
```